# Is there any way to add a subheading to a table in python-docx?

Tags: python, json, docx, python-docx

Statement: I have tried to generate table from a JSON file and want it to auto numbering the subheading.

Is there any way to makes auto numbering works for a table under a paragraph heading? Should I have to do something with `table.style` or not?

This is what I want as an output:
[image: table.]

I want it to auto numbering the table heading to "3.1" below "3 Chapter Three".

Sorry for any grammatical mistakes. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried for getting number for heading? They do have styles available, did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
styleParagraph = document.add_paragraph("Hello it me")
styleParagraph.style = 'Heading 1'
```